Trajectory in uniform gravitational field from least action
In Landau & Lifshitz' "Mechanics", 3e, pg. 143, the following differential equation for the trajectory of a particle is derived as a consequence of Maupertuis' principle of least action:
$$
\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{d\ell^2}=\frac{\vec{F}-(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{t})\vec{t}}{2(E-U)}
$$
where $\vec{r}$ is the position of the particle, $d\ell$ is an element of its path, $\vec{F}=-\partial U/\partial\vec{r}$ is the force acting on the particle, and $\vec{t}=d\vec{r}/d\ell$ is a unit tangent vector to the path.
I would like to solve this equation for the case $U=mgy$; i.e. a particle of mass $m$ moving through a uniform gravitational field. Assuming that the motion is confined to the $xy$ plane, it is well-known from Newtonian mechanics that the trajectory we should find is a parabola. My confusion lies with the object $d^2\vec{r}/d\ell^2$: given that $d\ell^2=dx^2+dy^2$ is the arc length, how am I to interpret the quantity $d^2\vec{r}/d\ell^2=d^2\vec{r}/(dx^2+dy^2)$?

Yes, $d\ell$ should be read as arc-length.

@Semiclassical Thank you. I realized that I didn't phrase the question well. Could you check the revised version?

I'd assume the derivatives should be computed as follows. Suppose for simplicity we consider a trajectory starting with zero $y$-velocity. Then $x,y$ and $\ell$ are all bijective functions of $t>0$. Hence we can invert these to express $x,y$ as functions of $\ell$ and thus compute derivatives with respect to $\ell$. (This is at least in principle valid: I don't relish doing the above by hand, though extensive use of the chain rule may help facilitate this.)
